# Cant connect Jetpack to wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I have installed the `jetpack` plugin but I cant connect it to my website. When I
click the connect button, nothing happens. My browser tries to load but nothing happens.At the end it shows an error like this:

```
cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 60002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

What should I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error (among others like HTTP[403]). Make sure to deactivate all other plugins, there is a known list of known conflicting plugins: https://jetpack.com/support/getting-started-with-jetpack/known-issues/ (Including typical ones like iThemes security, W3 Total cache, WP All Export )

If you use a CDN or Cloudflare it may be worthwhile checking out that help article: `http://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218377098-WordPress-JetPack-and-CloudFlare`

Also it seems that for some deactivating, uninstalling, and reinstalling Jetpack helps.

Also check your XMLRPC file. You can do this by going to your web site URL and adding “`/xmlrpc.php`” to the end (without the quotes). When it loads in your browser, you should see “XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.” on a line by itself. Common causes for this, again, are plugins or themes conflicting.

I had tried all of the above and the final thing to let it connect was php.ini configuration changes. Beyond the typical ones like increasing memory:

```
    memory_limit = 512M
    upload_max_filesize = 100M
    post_max_size = 512M
    max_execution_time = 300
    max_input_time = 300
```

... this was the one to fix it:
        `output_buffering = 2048`

I was using HostGator but I have a feeling other shared hosting environments like GoDaddy may have the same issue.

I wrote an article going through all the steps I took beyond that ( http://www.gordowebdesign.com/wordpress-troubleshooting-jetpack-failed-connection-curl-error-28-operation-timed-out-after-1000-milliseconds-with-0-bytes-received-solved/ ). Deactivate all other plugins before going further, and check that list. One of them is most likely the culprit.

Also it is worthwhile to run the debugger and check the output for helpful information:
`http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack-debugger`
or visit `http://jetpack.com/support/debug/` and add your URL.

If this doesnt work make sure to enable `define('JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php`

(Need more reputation to post those as links, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

if you hosting wordpress on your own computer, and if you run PHP as FastCGI, please check if system environment variable PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN is set to value more than 1.
Reason for that is following: when you click "connect", plugin is storing security tokens into your database, then Wnotifies www.wordpress.com and WAITS [to cleanup security tokens when validation is over]. which validates security tokens by making request to your wordpress site -- this should use another instance of PHP FastCGI [remember, first one is WAITING, and you need another one to respond].
Fix is: set system environment variable PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8 (or at least 2), then restart PHP FastCGI service or process [depending on how you run it]. -- you may want to check if FastCGI processes were started. then try to connect again.